# Styling deleted questions in post lists for awarded badges

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, badges, deleted-questions, design

On the list of flagged posts (*Flagging Summary*), deleted posts are shown as such:

> [image]

In the favorites list, they also appear deleted:

[image]

---

Deleted posts are not indicated on lists of posts for which users have received a badge, which, in the screenshot below, is every list item except two (the WinZip and passwords topics):

> [image]

<sup>Consistent with the flagging page, `[closed]`/`[migrated]` is shown only for the questions, not the answers.</sup>

---

Not showing this is

- **inconsistent** with the mentioned flagging summary and favorites pages,
- possibly **misleading to lower rep users**, since they won't be able to view the topics without any indication prior to clicking the link,
- and **misleads users regarding the availability of these badges**: From the topic overview, it seems that *Great Answer* is a comparatively easy to get badge, when, given today's moderation practices, it's just not.

Styling the list of posts for which badges were awarded similar to the list in the flagging summary, by adding a *deleted question background color* to the deleted posts would solve these problems.

Comment: By the way: **More than half of the posts** for which gold badges (excluding the 10k views badge) were awarded (79 of 153) are **deleted or were completely removed**.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what occurred to me: In the spirit of [forbidding 20k users to even search for *just the number* of deleted posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/107715/159624), I think it's funny that you can still get a list of deleted posts by looking at badges.

The difference to posts shown in the flag queue is that you (as the flagging user) *need* some visual representation of a post that due to a flag – in most cases – ended up being deleted.

---

For these badges however, it would actually be more consistent to

- remove badges awarded for deleted posts entirely, *or …*
- not show the deleted posts at all (or, show them only for ≥10k)

In fact, this already happens with the badge that by design is only awarded for deleted posts, namely [*Disciplined*](https://superuser.com/badges/35/disciplined):

> [image]

Comment: It's policy to not remove previously awarded badges. And here's the difference between *Disciplined* and *Great Answer*: The posts that earned the latter were really popular, and only ever deleted because the content became subjective or off topic due to site content policy changes. It's not like these users need to embarrassed about these posts (except for getting the badge for posting "Firefox" or "7zip"). This simply does not apply to the majority of deleted posts, that are inappropriate, spam, hate speech, wrong, etc.; including presumably many of those that earned the *Disciplined* badge.

Comment: I mean, imagine you were able to search for swear words, spam, or hate speech indicators, and compiled and published a list of the users and their posts. Or `user:22317 deleted:1` if you're interested in badmouthing a specific person. That's a shit storm right at the horizon. In contrast, what's the worst that can happen to recipients of a positive badge for a deleted posts?

Comment: You have a point with not removing badges. If it's been like this, then it should stay. One could argue though how many *Disciplined* posts actually fall under those categories you mentioned. At least they had a score of 3 or higher.

Comment: Regarding searching for deleted posts, it still makes sense in fighting spam. Searching for deleted content would just help make a better case. And I don't believe someone with ≥20k would just badmouth a user if it wasn't for any *active* (non-deleted) posts. But well, everything *can* happen, of course. I'll agree with your last sentence though. Maybe it would even be a signpost for: "If you post these answers to super-popular off-topic questions, they'll be deleted anyway" :P

Comment: Sorry, confused it with *Peer Pressure*, which is `-3` and behaves identically. Good question about the *Disciplined* badge. Probably since they are both similar and therefore share the implementation.

Comment: Another issue: You simply *expect* all posts in Peer Pressure/Disciplines to be deleted (they can be undeleted, but, come on...), while the other post badges are for questions that are interesting or considered good by a lot of users. The assumption is that they aren't regularly deleted. It just happened here, with the redefinition of what's an acceptable question over time.

Comment: That's true – it's not really consistent this way, considering this as well.